# Issue while understanding gravity/radius of earth graph

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets

I have following question.

**What are my opinions?**

> **1. Option 1 - This is incorrect.** I think dotted line in option 1 from bottom to peak represents center to surface of earth. After the peak, line starts to
> lower but then showing moving constantly. As we know value of gravity
> decrease as we go down or up the surface. So this is incorrect.
>
> **2. Option 2 - This option seems correct.** Line started from earth center and kept increasing till surface of earth(till dotted line at
> peak). then as we go lower the surface, gravity decrease and becomes 0
> at center.
>
> **3. Option 3 - This is incorrect.** As according to the graph, gravity is constant from center to surface of earth.
>
> **4. Option 4 - Incorrect.** According to graph, gravity remains constant after reaching surface of earth

Can you please check my understanding and add/edit if I Missed or misunderstood anything

[image]

Comment: (b) says there’s no gravity 6400 km above the surface of the Earth. Do you think that’s correct?

Comment: *I think dotted line in option 1 from bottom to peak represents center to surface of earth.* The horizontal axis from $r=0$ to $r=R$ represents this. The vertical coordinate does not indicate location.

Comment: Note that the image gives options a, b, c and d, but you use options 1, 2, 3 and 4.  Try and avoid things like that, it can, in general, create confusion.

Comment: "a" is the correct answer.  Talk to your teacher or professor for more details on why this answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

From all your sketches a) is he best and ok if at 2R the value is 1/4 of the value at R.

Comment: I think dotted line in option 1 from bottom to peak represents center to surface of earth. After the peak, line starts to lower but then started moving constantly. As we know value of gravity decrease as we go down or up the surface. So should it be incorrect? I am not sure. Please help.

Comment: In a) it is not true that "then started moving constantly" it just does descend slower. it looks like 1/r^2